# Is there any way I can find an application specific UUID for an iPhone / App, using Windows?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows

I have customers who do not have XCode or even a mac, so when I need them to go get the UUID that is produced when my application is installed on their iPhone, they cannot go and get that value for me to place on my test servers because they don't have xcode to gather the log / console level data.

Does anyone know of a way or location where that data might be stored in windows, or a software that can go get that?

Comment: Google it: https://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+UUID&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.yahoo:en-US:official&client=firefox&channel=sb

Comment: Can you explain why you need the app's UUID? You do know that it will change every time the user installs an update to your app, right?

Comment: install iTunes in Windows

Comment: Stellar input Mr. Mayes. :)  I Googled for a good 60 minutes, couldn't find much.   

rmaddy - I need the UUID to test push notifications to the specific device level.  For Mac users, I can point them towards XCode to go grab the UUID from the app after install, via console logs. 

For windows users though I can't figure out how to get that same info.